# Solution subspace of linear system and its basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

> Given the system of equations:
>
> $$x_2+3x_3-x_4+2x_5=0$$
>
> $$2x_1+3x_2+x_3+3x_4=0$$
>
> $$x_1+x_2-x_3+2x_4-x_5=0$$
>
> The solution is a subspace in $\mathbb{R}^5.$ Determine a basis for this subspace.

Starting with matrix
$
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 2 & 1 \\
  1 & 3 & 1 \\
  3 & 1 &-1 \\
 -1 & 3 & 2 \\
  2 & 0 &-1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$
I got the reduced matrix
$
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 &-\frac12 \\
  0 & 1 & \frac12 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$.

The solution I got is:

$$(x_1,x_2,x_3)=t(1/2,-1/2,1),t\in \mathbb{R}$$

How do I determine a basis with only one vector? Obviously they have to be linearly independent.

---

Never mind, I messed up. I accidentally transposed the matrix without noticing. I should get more sleep. The new solution I got was:

$$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)=t_1(4,-3,1,0,0)+t_2(-3,1,0,1,0)+t_3(3,-2,0,0,1)$$

Which is correct.

Comment: Shouldn't your solution be for $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$? How many free variables appear in your reduced system?

Comment: Only one. Rows 3, 4 and 5 in reduced form are zero vectors.

Comment: What are your free variables when in reduced form?  For each free variable, you get a basis vector (with 5 elements).

Comment: This is the reduced matrix I get. From that, I only have one free variable:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & -1/2 \\
        0 & 1 & 1/2 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: You are transposed.  And put any work that you have done in the original post, and not in the comments.

Comment: You're right, give me a minute.

Comment: As other users said in the above comments, knowing how you obtained the (incorrect) solution is rather essential for the answers - otherwise they cannot say what you did wrong. I believe it can be more-or-less guessed from your comments what you did. Please, check my edit, and if what I wrote is substantially different from what you did, then edit your post again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sketch:

Step 1: Create the augmented matrix for this system.

Step 2: Row reduce the system into reduced row echelon form.

Step 3: Turn your system back into equations

Step 4: Solve for your pivot variables in terms of your free variables.

Step 5: One at a time, set one free variable equal to $1$ and the remaining free variables equal to $0$.  The values of all variables in this case (pivot and free) form your basis vectors.

Comment: What if my row reduced system only contains one free variable? See above for what it looks like.

Comment: That is not the augmented system.  The augmented system should have five columns and three rows.